# How do I make my own object like: Set objIE = CreateObject( "InternetExplorer.Application" )?

Tags: createobject

How do I make a 'createobject'?

Any useful links/tutorials (or comment) about how to make a 'creatobject' would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a COM object that expose IDispatch https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608(v=vs.85).aspx, and register your class in the registry to make it possible to create an instance by name with createobject.

Which programming language/platform/tools are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual C++

Comment: Have a look at this sample/tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221186(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oke , thx for the link...now i have an idea how much work it is....lets say pretty much...so i don't' know if i give it a try.

Comment: If using some other languages and tools, a lot of that plumbing work is done for you. I think there are also templates in VC++ that take care of most of it, but the tutorial/sample shows all details to give an insight into how it works